# creating new default settings in iPhone App on the fly

Tags: iphone, settings, default

is it possible to create new default settings in an iPhone App on the fly?

I know how to modify existing ones but have not been able to find some code snippets to create brand new ones.

Your help is much appreciated.

Kind Regards

Vlad

Answer (score 0):

You need to use NSUserDefaults.... look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for documentation and [here](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSUserDefaults) for an example on how to use it.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I tried this already and it works.

However, the newly created settings do not appear in the iPhone Settings under my App for the user to see and modify.

So, I am sort of looking for ways to extend my Settings.bundle file on the fly.